# Change css style default button in panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have aspx page.
This page include several asp:Panel with attribute DefaultButton.

How I can change css style this defaultbutton after change active panel?

Comment: "after change active panel?"  what's that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a pure css way to do it. But with some javascript it's not too bad.

```
<script>
    var refreshButtons = function (specialButtonName="") {
        document.getElementById('Button1').style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
        document.getElementById('Button2').style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
        document.getElementById(specialButtonName).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
</script>
```

Then add a mouseover handler on your panels:

```
onmouseover="refreshButtons('Button1')"
```

I wanted it to be superdynamic, but the DefaultButton attrib doesn't survive the transformation from panel to div.